# How to Install IPA to an IOS device, do not use ITUNES, How to do ?

Tags: ios, ipa

I want to achieve an IPA IOS installed on other devices, but does not require authorization how to make!

Comment: you can use testFiliegt or OTA for achieve this.

Comment: You can use iphoneconfigurationutility to install  ipa to an iOS device.

Comment: We want to be a helper IOS, IOS to install genuine software through the code, so they need to be modified info.plist and iTunesMetadata.plist, so I really want to know is how to install the IOS Device to another; 
         A developer from China, http://tg.xyzs.com/dt/pc.php?ref=baidu&wid=78, XY apple assistant can be installed without jailbreak, I would like to know how he did it?

Answer (score 2):

use *http://diawi.com/*

Upload your IPA file there and they send link to your devices, and you can install by clicking on the link. No registration required..

Answer (score 2):

If you are developer and want to test your app on iDevice then use proper provisioning profile and build your ipa file and try this website

www.diawi.com

upload your ipa file and they give you link to install on idevice

OR

You are regular user and want to install random ipa file to iDevice then try using 
i-funbox
http://www.i-funbox.com/

Answer (score 1):

Post the app on a secure web server; you then access and perform the installation wirelessly. You can use resources such as Diawi or TestFlight. Alternatively, you can use iPhone Configuration Utility to install the IPA.